# PyQt: qthread interruption through signals

Tags: qt, pyqt, signals, pyqt4, qthread

I'm pretty new to pyqt, so I hope there won't be anything strange in what I'm trying to do. I was trying to create an interaction between QThreads by using PyQt signals. In particular, what I would like to do is to emit a signal from a thread, and this signal should interrupt what the thread is doing to run a specific method. By the way, I'm having some problems doing that, so I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is legal.

For instance, now I was trying to do something like this:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui as qt
from PyQt4 import QtCore as qtcore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread
import threading

app = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
class widget(qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        qtcore.QObject.__init__(self)


    def appinit(self):
        self.mysignal = qtcore.SIGNAL("mysignal")
        thread = mythread(self)
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(5)
        print "before emit",str(threading.current_thread())
        self.emit(self.mysignal,"hello, I'm thread "+str(threading.current_thread()))
        print "after emit",str(threading.current_thread())



class mythread(QThread):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        qtcore.QThread.__init__(self, parent=app)
        self.parent=parent

    def run(self):
        self.mysignal = qtcore.SIGNAL("mysignal")
        self.connect(self.parent, self.mysignal, self.myfunc)
        for i in range(15):
            print "**",threading.current_thread(),i
            time.sleep(1)

    def myfunc(self, msg):
        print threading.current_thread(), msg, "Enter"
        time.sleep(5)
        print threading.current_thread(), msg, "Exit"


def main():
    mywidget = widget()
    mywidget.show()
    qtcore.QTimer.singleShot(0, mywidget.appinit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

The output I get is:

```
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 0
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 1
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 2
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 3
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 4
before emit <_MainThread(MainThread, started 2928)>
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 2928)> hello, I'm thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 2928)> Enter
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 5
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 6
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 7
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 8
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 9
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 2928)> hello, I'm thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 2928)> Exit
after emit <_MainThread(MainThread, started 2928)>
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 10
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 11
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 12
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 13
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 1968)> 14
```

I would have actually expected mythread to interrupt its execution and to run myfunc. By the way, mythread doesn't interrupt its execution, and the function myfunc is actually run by the main thread. I tried to do the reverse (the generated thread sends a signal to the main thread) and it works.

I guess I have not understood exactly how signals work and if it's possible to do what I would like. Any clue about that? I looked online for a solution, but with no result.

Thanks

Comment: Interrupting synchronous code like a long-running loop via signal won't work: signal/slots across threads need an event loop in the receiving thread (i.e. it must be entered in run(), by calling exec()); to have the slot called, the receiving thread must return to the event loop; I.e. if you have a long running loop, the event loop will be blocked and the slot never called.

Comment: I think I'm starting understanding better now. By the way, I replaced the for loop in mythread.run() with app.exec_(). The result is that the function myfunc is still called by the main thread, so I feel something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , from what i could understand is that you want the thread to enter a 5 second sleep before it iterates further.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui as qt
from PyQt4 import QtCore as qtcore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread
import threading

app = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
class widget(qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        qtcore.QObject.__init__(self)


    def appinit(self):
        self.mysignal = qtcore.SIGNAL("mysignal")
        thread = mythread(self,self.mysignal)
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(5)
        print "before emit",str(threading.current_thread())
        self.emit(self.mysignal,"hello, I'm thread "+str(threading.current_thread()))
        print "after emit",str(threading.current_thread())



class mythread(QThread):
    def __init__(self,parent,sig):
        qtcore.QThread.__init__(self, parent=app)
        self.parent=parent
        self.mysignal = sig
        self.stop_event=threading.Event()
        self.connect(self.parent, self.mysignal, self.setIt)

    def run(self):

        for i in range(15):
            if self.stop_event.isSet():
                self.myfunc()
            print "**",threading.current_thread(),i
            time.sleep(1)

    def setIt(self,msg):
        self.stop_event.set()
        self.msg = msg

    def myfunc(self):
        print threading.current_thread(),self.msg ,  "Enter"
        time.sleep(5)
        print threading.current_thread(),self.msg ,  "Exit"
        self.stop_event.clear()


def main():
    mywidget = widget()
    mywidget.show()
    qtcore.QTimer.singleShot(0, mywidget.appinit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

Output :

```
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 0
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 1
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 2
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 3
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 4
before emit <_MainThread(MainThread, started 232)>
after emit <_MainThread(MainThread, started 232)>
<_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> hello, I'm thread <_MainThread(MainThread,     started 232)> Enter
<_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> hello, I'm thread <_MainThread(MainThread,     started 232)> Exit
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 5
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 6
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 7
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 8
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 9
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 10
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 11
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 12
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 13
** <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7312)> 14
```